# i dont know what what is the error its printing 3.18e+04

Tags: precision

```
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

double A,R;

    R=100.64;
    R=R*R;
    A=3.14159*R;
    cout<< setprecision(3)<<A<<endl;
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: That output looks about right to me.

Comment: `3.18e+04` means `3.18*10**4` or `31800`.  It's scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

The reasonably precise and accurate<sup>(a)</sup> value you would get from those calculations (mathematically) is `31,819.31032`.

You have asked for a precision of three digits and, with that value and the floating point format currently active (probably `std::defaultfloat`), it's only giving you three significant digits:

- `3.18e+04` (`3.18x104` in mathematical form).

If your intent is to instead show three digits *after* the decimal point, you can do that with the `std::fixed` manipulator:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double R = 100.64;
    double A = 3.14159 * R * R;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed << A << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This gives `31819.310`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Make sure you never conflate these two, they're different concepts. See for example, the following values of `π` you may come up with:

| Value | Properties |
| --- | --- |
| `9` | Both im-precise and in-accurate. |
| `3` | Im-precise but accurate. |
| `2.718281828459` | Precise but in-accurate. |
| `3.141592653590` | Both precise and accurate. |
| `π` | Has maximum precision and accuracy. |